# Facing issues writing code with perl expect

Tags: linux, perl

I want to run a command which will connect to a remote host and perform some actions, while I try to run the command below actions are required.

```
The authenticity of host 'test.example.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 45:57:9e:d6:6f:b5:cc:c6:00:3f:90:ec:a1:9d:4e:5f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Please type 'yes' or 'no':
```

also it asks for a password as below

```
tes@test.example.com's password:
```

I have written a perl script as below:

```
sub user_expect()
{
    print "==== Now executing the following command:\n";
    print "$cmd\n";
    $exp = new Expect();
    $exp->raw_pty(1);
    $exp->log_file("output2_user", "w");
    $exp->debug($debug);
    $exp->spawn("$cmd");
    $exp->expect($timeout,'-re', '\?\s$'); # Authenticity question (yes/no)
    $exp->send("yes\n");
    $exp->expect($timeout,'-re', ':\s$'); # In case on console am expected to type yes/no - Please type 'yes' or 'no': 
    $exp->send("yes\n");
    $exp->expect($timeout,'-re', 'word:$'); # enter password
    $exp->send("xyz\n");
    $exp->expect(500,'-re', 'mailbox deleted successfully\.$');
    $exp->hard_close();
    return 1;
}
```

I needed a code which can answer the questions asked on console i.e. as below and also the password console

```
The authenticity of host 'test.example.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 45:57:9e:d6:6f:b5:cc:c6:00:3f:90:ec:a1:9d:4e:5f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Please type 'yes' or 'no':
```

I am not sure on the mistake I have done regarding the script, can someone please help ?

Problem is - I think the "yes" that needs to be typed for below query is not taken because of which the query "Please type 'yes' or 'no': " is shown on console. Then my script stops there and does not proceed with password prompt.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Comment: Apologies, did not mention the problem faced.. I have updated it now

Comment: You can get around that issue by setting up your ssh config ( ~/.ssh/config ) file with an entry like: 
Host test.example.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no

Comment: Alternatively, just login to that server once, and then it will be added to your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file so it won't ask you again.  ( More secure way )

Comment: I tried to add an entry to ssh config and also logged into the server.. but still am getting the authenticity question, saw entry in known_hosts and could see entry of the server, please let me know for any other options ?

Comment: you can add `ssh_option => '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'`  to constructor and check if it is working for you.

Comment: @AruneshSingh can i please know how to set `ssh_option => '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'` in perl expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code as below, it was successful:

```
sub rehostuser_expect() {
    $expect= Expect->new;
    $expect->raw_pty(1);
    $expect->spawn($cmd)
    or die "Cannot spawn $cmd: $!\n";

    $expect->expect($timeout,
            [   qr/.*\?/i, #/
            sub {
                    my $self = shift;
                    $self->send("yes\r\n");
                    exp_continue;
                    }
            ]);

    $expect->expect($timeout,
            [   qr/password:/i, #/
            sub {
                    my $self = shift;
                    $self->send("$password\n");
                    exp_continue;
            }
    ]);
    $expect->hard_close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-2.01/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) instead of using Expect module. You need to set strict_host_key_checking => 'no' if you want to skip SSH key checking...

Comment: I need to run a command in same server which connects to another host to perform some actions and the command expects the password (along with authenticity part (yes/no)). In Net::SSH::Perl, everywhere I see that it first connects to another server and runs the command. Please let me know how to run a command and then provide password and authenticity using Net::SSH::Perl?